# iOS: Child View Controller and Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, autolayout, childviewcontroller

I have a very simple scenario that is not working for me. I have one storyboard with two view controllers:

```
ViewController1
- ViewA
- ViewB

ViewController2
- ViewC
```

My `ViewController1` is working as intended and when I rotate the device the views adjust correctly according to the auto layout that I defined.

My `ViewController2` have a Freeform size (768x722) and I unchecked the option "Resize View From Nib".

This is my `ViewController1` `didLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *vc2 = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"];

    [self addChildViewController:vc2];
    [vc2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.viewA addSubview:vc2.view];
}
```

When I rotate the device the method `- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` from `ViewControlled2` its called and it shows the correct orientation. However, `ViewC` does not resize it self and does not follow my Auto Layout settings.

Anyone know how I can fix? I just want to add my `ViewController2` inside `ViewA` and keep the Auto Layout working for views of `ViewController2`. I need a solution for iOS 7 only, so no compatibility with earlier versions is needed.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: you will need to post your constraints and a screenshot of your view.

Comment: my constraints are correct. For example, if I replace viewA for a ContainerView and link the container segue to ViewController2 it works. However, I have others ViewControllers in my storyboard that can be added to ViewA, so I need to do it programmatically and when I do the rotation does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution and I will register it here, just in case someone needs it.

I created an UIViewController property to hold my ViewController2. After that, I added the following method:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    self.vc2.view.frame = self.viewA.bounds;
}
```

Comment: As an add, if you call the method from the child view controller, you can use `self.view.frame = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;`